# iframe content disappears after hiding wrapping div

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am showing a pdf file in an iframe element, but usually the iframe is hidden, because I hide the wrapping div. For my application it is necessary to **hide** (display: none) the div. Unfortunately the iframe apparently loses its content after I hide the div. I isolated the effect in the follwing code. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="show()">Show</button>
  <button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
  <div id="test">
    <iframe src="https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~luedde/Lecture/Mechanik/Intranet/Skript/MechanikSkript.pdf" width="800" height="900" id="myFrame"></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>
    function show() {
      document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block"

      //Solution that works, but causes unnecessary loading
      //-------------------------------------------------------------- 
      //document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~luedde/Lecture/Mechanik/Intranet/Skript/MechanikSkript.pdf"
    }

    function hide() {
      document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none"
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

After initial loading
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGeo6.jpg

After hiding and showing
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxrwA.jpg

---

Edit: I found another interesting effect. When I load a PDF from an websource, the file is visible after hiding and showing the div. But if I load the pdf locally from origin the issue appears.

Comment: Without an actual PDF to display, your snippet does not currently sucessfully reproduce the issue. But I am guessing that this is an idiosyncrasy of the PDF viewer, that it “unloads” the rendered content when the element gets hidden, perhaps for performance reasons. Have you tried hiding the element using other means than `display:none`? Like setting width & height to 1px (don’t use 0, that can cause problems again), overflow & visibility to hidden?

Comment: I tried to link a external pdf but probably because of Cross-Origin restriction this doesn't work. So if you want to try this, you'll need to try it locally. Like I said, i need display: none!

Comment: _“Like I said, i need display: none!”_ - why? What specifically do you need regarding the behavior, so that a different method of visually hiding it from the user does _not_ do the job?

Comment: Because its part of a whole concept. And the iframe is implemented into an div which gets hidden by a specific function, I dont want to change for this issue. I just want to understand why this is happening and how other people maybe solved it. Using an other visibility attribute for the div would only be a quick fix, but I want a stable solution which works in my environment. I also dont change a room, because a table doesnt fit through the door :)

Comment: did you try  visibility: hidden instead of display: none?

Comment: please read the comments above

Comment: _“I also dont change a room, because a table doesnt fit through the door”_ - so what do you do instead then, huh? You either get a different table (that would be what was suggested to you here), or you live with the fact that you’ll be sitting in a room without any table (i.e., your PDF display simply not working correctly.)

Comment: _“I just want to understand why this is happening and how other people maybe solved it.”_ - I gave you a possible explanation, and a suggestion what I would first of all try as a workaround. _“Using an other visibility attribute for the div would only be a quick fix, but I want a stable solution which works in my environment.”_ - and who says there was any to begin with? You have something here that is not working as intended (whether due to a bug, or intentionally implemented this way), so you’ll need a _workaround_. And one was already suggested to you.

Comment: When run in Firefox, Chrome and Edge it hides and shows fine. So could be your browser.

Comment: _“And the iframe is implemented into an div which gets hidden by a specific function, I dont want to change for this issue.”_ - just more proof for the already known fact, that stuff like this should rather not be done by manipulating inline styles directly, but by changing/setting a class instead. Then you could simply write a rule in your stylesheet, that applies a _different_ method of hiding this particular element, without any modification to the JS part.